# JPA/Hibernate mapping table for One-to-many relationships

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-many

I'm using JPA annotations only and hibernate 4.0.1 as the JPA implementation.

I have an`Assessment`class that has two sets of `Comment`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ASSESSMENT")
public class Assessment{

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Comment> auditComments = new HashSet<Comment>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Comment> comments = new HashSet<Comment>();
}
```

*(I'm skipping getters, setters, cascade annotations and other irrelevant lines of code)*

Comment:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "COMMENT")
public class Comment{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "text")
    private String text;
}
```

Now, because a `Comment` doesn't have a reference back to `Assessment` (this is on purpose), I cannot uset the *mappedBy* property and Hibernate needs to create a mapping table between `Comment` and `Assessment`. By default, it is named ASSESSMENT_COMMENT.

If I had only one set of `Comment` in `Assessment`, that would work perfectly fine. The ASSESSMENT_COMMENT would have only two columns:

```
[ASSESSMENT_ID, COMMENT_ID]
```

which will perfectly represent the one-to-many relationship.

**Now here is the problem:**

Because I don't have one set of `Comment` but two, Hibernate tries to map the two sets using only one ASSESSMENT_COMMENT table. This table has 3 columns:

```
[ASSESSMENT_ID, COMMENT_ID, AUDITCOMMENT_ID]
```

On top of that, the 3 columns are set as non nullable.

That certainly cannot work. For instance, if I have only one item in auditComents and  none in  comments, hibernate tries to insert one row with a null in COMMENT_ID which creates a SQL exception.

**Questions:**

To me it looks like a bug. There should be two mapping tables, not one.

So, 1) is it a known bug in Hibernate? 2) is there a way around that? Can I force Hibernate to create two mapping tables, one for each of the set. Bear  in mind that I cannot change the `Comment` class to have a reference to `Assessment` (business logic requirement)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, you could use two columns in the comment table to point back to their assessment:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "audit_commented_assessment_id")
private Set<Comment> auditComments = new HashSet<Comment>();

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "commented_assessment_id")
private Set<Comment> comments = new HashSet<Comment>();
```

If you want two join tables, the just say so:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "assessment_audit_comment",
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "assessment_id"),
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "comment_id"))
private Set<Comment> auditComments = new HashSet<Comment>();

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "assessment_comment",
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "assessment_id"),
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "comment_id"))
private Set<Comment> comments = new HashSet<Comment>();
```

That is of course explained in [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/manual/en-US/html_single/#collections-mapping).

Comment: Thanks it fixed it. I never had two collection of the same type so I never had to use the @JoinTable annotation.

Comment: How would the Comment class look if you would like to have a bidirectional relation? E.g. in the Comment POJO I would like to have a reference to an Assessment? You can not use two @jointable (one against each mapping table of the parent)? How would you do it?

Comment: @nize: If the associations were bidirectional, you would have to make Comment the owner side of the associations. In Comment, you would have a field `commentedAssessment` and a field `auditedAssessment`. They would be mapped with `@ManyToOne`, with a join table as above, but with joinColumns and inverseJoinColumns switched. In Assessment, you would simply have `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "auditedAssessment") private Set<Comment> auditComments;` and `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "commentedAssessment") Set<Comment> comments;`

Comment: Ok, but assume the case is that a comment must either be a auditComment OR a comment, not both. That is why I would like to have the Comment to only have a reference "Assessment parent", not two references "commentedAssessment" and "auditedAssessment". Would that be possible to achieve or do I need to have two references of which one always will be NULL? Maybe then I need to extend Comment with two classes, AuditComment and NormalComment?

Comment: I tried that path, but I experienced it to be a mess since the mappedBy reference to the superclass didn't work as I expected. I decided to try another alternative: In the class Assessment I have the List<Comment> comments. In the Comment class I use a boolean isAuditComment. Then I can provide methods in the Assessment class like List<Comment> getAuditingComments() and List<Comment> getOtherComments(). Not as elegant, but less complex from a JPA perspective.