# How to insert data into mapping table?

Tags: java, spring, database, spring-boot, rest

I have 2 tables and one more table to map relation of my previous 2 tables, How can I insert data into the mapped table efficiently and automatically using Spring Data JPA ?
Below is the table structure.

User (id (PK), name, email, userRoleId)
Role (id (PK), name, userRoleId) 
UserRole (id (PK), userId (FK <- User), roleId (FK <- Role))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JPA/Hibernate mapping table for One-to-many relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13876799/jpa-hibernate-mapping-table-for-one-to-many-relationships)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use @Builder annotation in spring
For example here

1. Foreign key entity User
   User userDetailToSave = User.builder.id(getId).build();
2. Foreign key entity Role
   Role roleDetailToSave = Role.builder.id(getId).build();
3. Save in the DATABASE
   UserRole userDetailToSave = UserRole.builder().id(getId).userId(userDetailToSave).roleId(roleDetailToSave).build();
   UserRoleRepo.save(userDetailToSave);

Comment: That is manual,
is there any way that this can be done automatically ?
Because I am inserting data into User table and in the Role table both, so is there any way that the mapping table can be filled automatically by using these two tables data.

Comment: This should be done as mentioned above. The reason is - It is necessary to have maintained the referential relationship between the tables. If you are inserting the values in the UserRole table then the parent tables must have those key present in their table.
Hope you understood my words.